# Solaris 10 snmp exec multiple strings

Tags: solaris, snmp, net-snmp, exec

I am trying to use snmp to query a directory listing. I have added the exec line to snmp.conf ("exec list /bin/ls /pathtodirectory") and restarted the service. When I perform an snmp walk for the exec OID I can see the string returned by the exec, but it is only the first line of the ls output. Is it possible to list the entire directory as one string or return multiple strings?

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In fact if you check the [man page for snmpd.conf](http://linux.die.net/man/5/snmpd.conf) you'll discover the `extend` directive:

> **extend [MIBOID] NAME PROG ARGS**
>   works in a similar manner to the exec
>   directive, but with a number of improvements. The MIB tables
>   (nsExtendConfigTable etc) are indexed by the NAME token, so are
>   unaffected by the order in which entries are read from the
>   configuration files. There are two result tables - one
>   (nsExtendOutput1Table) containing the exit status, the first line and
>   full output (as a single string) for each extend entry, and the other
>   (nsExtendOutput2Table) containing the complete output as a series of
>   separate lines.   If MIBOID is specified, then the configuration and
>   result tables will be rooted at this point in the OID tree, but are
>   otherwise structured in exactly the same way. This means that several
>   separate extend directives can specify the same MIBOID root, without
>   conflicting. The exit status and output is cached for each entry
>   individually, and can be cleared (and the caching behaviour
>   configured) using the nsCacheTable.

Comment: Extend is not defined under Solaris 10. It throws an error in the snmpd log when I try and use it. I thought I remember reading about being able to enable the module or something along those line sbut I cannot find it...

Comment: @user18832 Consider installing a more recent version of net-snmp...